# Adding Printer PowerShell Script File

Tags: powershell

I am trying to create a script that will allow a non admin user to run a script file to add printer drivers and then add the IP printer. The script I have works, but only as an administrator  to add the driver files to the Driver Store. I have a script to open PowerShell with stored credentials, but it will never run the file let alone as an administrator.

```
$username = "Domain\User"
$pass= ConvertTo-SecureString "Password" -AsPlainText -Force
$cred= new-object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($username, $pass)
$ps1="Path\To\File.ps1"
Start-Process -WorkingDirectory 'C:\Windows' powershell.exe -Credential $cred -ArgumentList "-Start-Process -FilePath $ps1 -Verb RunAs"
```

This currently has PowerShell open and immediately close.
Running `Start-Process -FilePath $ps1` in admin console also returns an error of "No application is associated with the specified file for this operation." even though I have set .ps1 to default to powershell.exe

Comment: why are you using `Start-Process` to run `Start-Process`?

Comment: Apart from the script not working right now I highly doubt that is a favorable concept as you are effectively giving your users credentials to an admin account that way. Why aren't you using the Microsoft supported way with GPOs like [in this example](https://theitbros.com/allow-non-admins-install-printer-drivers-via-gpo)?

Comment: I am running start process to open a PowerShell windows execute a script as an administrator. Just running the script with credentials isn't elevating the permissions.

Comment: I know it is not ideal to have the credentials stored this way, however, my manager has insisted that as users move from workstation to workstation or location to location, this is the solution they want for now.